# feh imageviewer endless cycle

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, slideshow, feh

I want to build something like a digital photoframe with my Raspberry Pi.

On the Raspberry is RaspianOS and the imageviewer *feh* (version 3.6.3) installed.
As I read from the documentation, I expect this command
`feh -qrYzFD10 ~/Pictures` to display images in an endless loop, so after the last image the slideshow restarts with the first image.
But if i run this command, the slideshow stops after the last image. In the documentation I could only find the parameter `--cycle-once` which stops the slideshow after the last image, but i want it to be endless.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: You haven't missed anything. quite, recursive, hide-pointer, randomize, full-screen, delay 10 sec and start at `~/Pictures`. The only guess I have is there are some images that are not compatible (e.g. `.webp`, etc..) that may cause `feh` to hang, but with `-q` you will never know. That said, you have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Another appropriate site is [Raspberry pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) However, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is likely the best in your case (I've asked a moderator to move your question there).

Comment: thanks for the hint. feh skips some images, but there are no errors even without -q

Comment: thats was it! i removed the image where feh stops the slideshow and it works as expected in an endless cycle. Thank you very much! And sorry for the wrong site, maybe an moderator could move the topic, so anyone with the same problem might find this solution?

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can close the question before the move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like David guessed it above, there was some issue with an image.
I deleted the first non shown image and it worked.
There was no error shown, only hint was the image was really big.